# PHP If, Elseif, Else Statement in Wordpress Header

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an H2 and a form at the top of my page, it is present on ever page and is in the Theme template, in header.php, but I need the content to change on 2 specific pages. The current code is this:

```
<h2 id="formhead">Buy, Hire or Enquire</h2>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="1" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]' ); ?>
```

I tried changing it to an if, elseif, else statement:

```
<?php
if (is_page('54')) {
<h2 id="formhead">Hire or Enquire</h2>
echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="3" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]' );
} elseif (is_page('52')) {
<h2 id="formhead">Buy or Enquire</h2>
echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="2" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]' );
} else {
<h2 id="formhead">Buy, Hire or Enquire</h2>
echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="1" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]' );
}
?>
```

This however, breaks the site completely and nothing loads. I have no real php experiance(I'm sure there is just a very basic error in the code), only what I've figured out by trial and error, but since this is going on a live site, I can't afford to constantly break the site.

Thanks in advance
Willem

Comment: there is an syntax error .. php tags are not been closed, turn error reporting on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open and close the php tags:

```
<?php
if (is_page('54')) { ?>
<h2 id="formhead">Hire or Enquire</h2>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="3" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]' );
} elseif (is_page('52')) { ?>
<h2 id="formhead">Buy or Enquire</h2>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="2" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]' );
} else { ?>
<h2 id="formhead">Buy, Hire or Enquire</h2> <?php
echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="1" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]' );
}
?>
```

Comment: We all have to start somewhere don't we? Glad i could help!

Answer (score 2):

You are using html in between php . So either use opening and closing php `<?php... ?>` or if single html line then you can just use `echo` as below

```
<?php
if (is_page('54')) {
    echo '<h2 id="formhead">Hire or Enquire</h2>';
    echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="3" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]');
} elseif (is_page('52')) {
    echo '<h2 id="formhead">Buy or Enquire</h2>';
    echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="2" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]');
} else {
    echo '<h2 id="formhead">Buy, Hire or Enquire</h2>';
    echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="1" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are right, but here's another syntax you can use when you mix PHP and HTML (which I prefer as I find it more readable):

```
<?php if (is_page('54')): ?>
    <h2 id="formhead">Hire or Enquire</h2>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="3" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]'); ?>
<?php elseif (is_page('52')): ?>
    <h2 id="formhead">Buy or Enquire</h2>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="2" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <h2 id="formhead">Buy, Hire or Enquire</h2>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="1" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (is_page('54')) {
?>
<h2 id="formhead">Hire or Enquire</h2>
<?php
echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="3" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]' );
} elseif (is_page('52')) {
?>
<h2 id="formhead">Buy or Enquire</h2>
<?php
echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="2" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]' );
} else {
?>
<h2 id="formhead">Buy, Hire or Enquire</h2>
<?php
echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="1" name="Contact Form" title="false" description="false"]' );
}
?>
```

That might work (untested)

You weren't opening and closing your PHP tags and your brackets were a bit off.